# Pymysql when executing Union query with %s (Parameter Placeholder)

Tags: python, mysql, database, pymysql

[image]

**This is the code about UNION QUERY:**

```
        smith ='Smith'
        smithb='Smith'

        sql="""SELECT Distinct Pnumber FROM PROJECT, DEPARTMENT, EMPLOYEE WHERE Dnum = Dnumber AND Mgr_ssn=Ssn AND Lname= %s 
        UNION SELECT Distinct Pnumber PROJECT, WORKS_ON, EMPLOYERE WHERE Pnumber =Pno AND Essn=Ssn AND Lname=%s"""

        curs.execute(sql,(smith,smithb))
        #curs.execute(sql2,('Smith'))
        conn.commit()     
        rows = curs.fetchall()
        print(rows)
```

**This is the err message!!:**

```
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE Pnumber =Pno AND Essn=Ssn AND Lname='Smith'' at line 1")
```

I need to know the pymysql union query syntax.Thank you.

Comment: I'm so sorry about poor view...

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `Lname= %s`  to `Lname LIKE '%s'`.